# Count non null values from a left joint table

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Count non-null values directly from select statement (not using where) on a left joint table

`count(*) as comments` Need this to provide count of non-null values only. Also, `inner join` is not a solution because, that does not include content which have zero comments in `count(distinct (t1.postId)) as no_of_content`

```
select  t1.tagId as tagId, count(distinct (t1.postId)) as no_of_content, count(*) as comments
from  content_created as t1
left join comment_created as t2 
on t1.postId=t2.postId
where   
(   (t1.tagId = "S2036623" )
 or  (t1.tagId = "S97422" )
)
group BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Though Posting the sample data might help us more to answer this but you can update your count function to -

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN postId IS NULL THEN 1 END) as comments
```

Answer (score 0):

Count only counts non-null values. What you need to do is reference the right hand side table's column explicitly. So instead of saying `count(*)` use `count(right_joined_table.join_key)`.
Here's a full example using BigQuery:

```
with left_table as (
select num
from unnest(generate_array(1,10)) as num
), right_table as (
select num
from unnest(generate_array(2,10,2)) as num
)

select
  count(*) as total_rows,
  count(l.num) as left_table_counts,
  count(r.num) as non_null_counts
from left_table as l
left outer join right_table as r
on l.num = r.num
```

This gives you the following results:

[image]